# How can I present VC and set as new Root viewController in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, appdelegate

I have this warning:
**Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged**

I need to know how can set my rootViewController in another VC and avoid this warning

I have this code in my VC:

```
@IBAction func dissmissInfo(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "firstVC")
     present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    })
```

And in the firstVC I have this:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = self
}
```

but when I try to move to another VC I have the same warning:
**Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean you want to set firstVC

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "firstVC")
```

as the new RootViewController?

If YES:

```
@IBAction func dissmissInfo(_ sender: UIButton) {
     let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
     let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "firstVC")
     UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = vc 
})
```

Then in firstVC, remove

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = self
```

Comment: Thanks this works fine, One last question this is possible animate like a transition modally?